# Why is $ \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx} \neq \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\int_{0}^{\pi/2}cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx} $

Tags: integration

Let's assume we have $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx}.$$

Usually it's possible to move the border and multiply the integral with $2$. Geometrically you cut the half and add it again afterwards to make calculation easier.
Obviously this isn't legal here but I can't see why (beside the obvious reason that it's simply not equal).

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx} &\neq \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx} \\
\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx} &= \frac{n \pi \cdot \sin[n \pi]}{1 - n^2} \\ 
\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx} &= 
\frac{j (1 + e^{-j n \pi}) n}{(1 - n^2) \pi}.
\end{align}

Comment: This is legal. Integration is linear and you can divide your main integral into $3$. Two of them vanish.

Comment: $e^{-jnx}\ne e^{-jn(-x)}$ so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only exploit symmetry when the integrand in question is even, i.e. when $f(-x)=f(x)$. In this case, $f(x)=\cos(x)\cdot e^{-jnx}$. It follows that $f(-x)=\cos(-x)\cdot e^{-jn(-x)}=\cos(x) \cdot e^{jnx}$. Thus, $f(-x)\neq f(x)$.